Dipoles as vectors
A triatomic molecule $X_2Y$ has plane structure as shown in figure. Due to difference in electronegativity, charge acquired by each X atom is $q$ and charge on Y atom is $- 2q$. The bond length between Y and X is d, and angle between the two bonds is 120° mass of one atom of X and Y are m and 8m respectively. The molecule is placed in a uniform Electric field $E$ and is making small oscillations about an axis perpendicular to the plane of figure and passing through the centre of mass of the molecule. Find the time period of oscillation.

My teacher has given me a solution to this problem by considering 2 dipoles along the bonds, taking their resultant and then moving it by a small amount in the plane of the electric field to solve for its time period.
What I don't understand is why we have defined a dipole as the product of the position vector of the positive charge with respect to the negative charge with the magnitude of charge.
Why does it make sense that the resultant of those dipoles would give the same time period as of the original dipole in the question?
Another thing which I wanted to ask is about finding the formula for electric field at any point at an angle $\theta$ (from the center of the dipole) due to a dipole. What our teacher did is that he took the components of the dipole along and perpendicular to the line joining that point and center of dipole and solved seperately for those axial and equatorial position, and took their resultant.
I want to ask why should this even work because we have defined dipole ourself and then taking their components and then superimposing them is it a law? (well I had asked these questions to my teacher too, and he said it's obvious, but it wasn't so for me). (also please pardon for the image I know I should have only uploaded the figure but I wasn't able to crop the picture anymore on my phone so I uploaded the whole picture)
Currently I'm in grade 12, India, and have studied upto the current and electricity chapter. If possible, please try to give an answer which a 12th grade student can understand.

If you want to make your question more readable, and thus attract more attention, you should add some punctuation! So, why we can sum the vector? Let us keep the two dipoles separated. Then calculate the force (or the torque): it is linear in the two vectors. Then, what you need is the sum of the forces. Since each force is linear in the dipole, then you can sum them from the beginning. Is this the point you are asking?

@DorianoBrogioli ok thanks for your method it seems obvious and easy to add the torque of those 2 dipoles and then find the time period but can you please explain why taking resultant of those 2 dipoles as vectors would produce a dipole with an equivalent time period and electric field as those 2 dipoles would do together?

Rotational dynamics. The governing equation of the rotational dynamics of a system w.r.t. to its center of mass reads
$$\frac{d \boldsymbol{\Gamma}_G}{dt} = \mathbf{M}_G^{ext} \ .$$
Considering only the rotation around the $z$-axis perpendicular w.r.t. the plane of the screen, for a rigid system (assuming the molecule as rigid, with the vibrational degree of freedoms freezed) the $z$-component of the angular momentum reads
$$\Gamma_{G,z} = I_{G,z} \, \dot{\alpha}\ , $$
where $\alpha$ is the rotation of the molecule and $I_{G,z}$ is the constant moment of inertia w.r.t. the center of mass.
Equivalent system. Since the angular momentum is additive and the sum of internal moments equals zero (for the third principle of mechanics), you can see the molecule as the union of two dipoles:

overall inertia is the sum of inertia of the two dipoles
total external moment is the sum of the moments acting on each dipole.

I see no peculiar reason to solve the problem in this way, but you can do it.

Small oscillations around the stable equilibrium.
Defining the origin of $\alpha$, $\alpha = 0$, as the stable equilibrium of the system, the determination of the period of the oscillations is evaluated for small oscillations around $\overline{\alpha} = 0$. For small value of $\alpha$, the momentum acting on each dipole is $M_{1,2} = - E p \cos(\pm 60° + \alpha)$ and the sum is
$$\begin{aligned}
M = M_1 + M_2 & = - E q d \left[ \sin(60°+\alpha) + \sin(-60° +\alpha)\right] =  \\
& = - E q d \left[ \sin(60°)\cos\alpha + \cos(60°)\sin\alpha + \sin(-60°)\cos\alpha + \cos(-60°)\sin(\alpha) \right] = \\
& = - 2 E q d \cos(60°) \sin \alpha  \sim \\ 
& \sim - 2 E q d \cos(60°) \alpha \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
with the approximation $\sin \alpha \sim \alpha$, for $\alpha \sim 0$.
Introducing the definition of the intensity of the dipoles, $p = q d$, the dynamical equation reads
$$I_{G,z} \ddot{\alpha} = - 2 E p \cos(60°) \alpha \ ,$$
or
$$\ddot{\alpha} + \frac{2 E p \cos(60°)}{I_{G,z} } \alpha = 0 \ ,$$
so that the angular frequency of the small-amplitude oscillation is $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2 E p \cos(60°)}{I_{G,z}}}$, and the period readily follows $T = \frac{2 \pi}{\omega}$.

Go! Anonymous downvoter, go!


"why does it make sense that the resultant of those dipoles would give the same time period as of the original question"

Your point is valid, it does feel and and seems misleading that the net motion of the two dipoles would be the same as the motion of the resultant dipole. But if you think of it the other way round, you can relate it to projectile motion.
There the net motion of the particle is broken down into its motion along the x and y axes, and thereafter it becomes very easy to write the equations of motion for the particle. 
Similarly here we are doing the opposite since, the motion of the molecule is easier when studied with respect to the resultant of the two dipoles (instead of it's components) . You can although solve for each dipole separately, but in the end when you take the resultant you will find that you get the same equation that you got from solving with respect to the resultant dipole.

"why should this even work because we have defined dipole ourself and then taking their components and then superimposing them is it a law?"

Law of superposition of vectors.
p.s: I am not providing a solution to the question since there's already an excellent one in one of the answers.
